# Trying to move items from one to the other

Tags: vb.net, winforms

]I am having strange problem when i try to move items from one grid view to another using a bindingsource it adding in an extra blank row some reason

```
Private Sub btnMove_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnMove.Click
    Dim bs As New BindingSource
    Dim a As Integer
    Dim removeList As List(Of infoRemoteFiles) = fileList
    For a = 0 To grdAvailFiles.SelectedRows.Count

        grdProcessFiles.Rows.Add(grdAvailFiles.Rows(a).Cells("filename").Value)

        removeList.RemoveAll(Function(p As infoRemoteFiles) p.filename = grdAvailFiles.Rows(a).Cells("filename").Value)


    Next
    bs.DataSource = removeList
    grdAvailFiles.DataSource = bs

End Sub
```

please see what i mean its the row below what I have selected I dont no where its comming from thanks

[image]

Comment: @MikyDinescu I no I was just debugging my code in the move button before making it global thanks can you please add a proper answer so I can mark you up

Comment: Done - I've added an answer with link to the relevant property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extra blank row is added automatically if you have the [AllowUserToAddRows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.windows.forms.datagridview.allowusertoaddrows%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property set to True on the DataGridView control.

From the documentation:

> If the DataGridView is bound to data, the user is allowed to add rows if both this property and the data source's IBindingList.AllowNew property are set to true.

On a separate note, you shouldn't have to create anew binding source (for the source data grid). Instead, modify the collection that is already bound to the DataSource property.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

For A = 0 To grdAvailFiles.SelectedRows.Count - 1

Note the minus 1, because you're starting from zero.